# Extracting image src in HTML with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

[image]

I tried to get the .png file's link with this code.

```
e = rawData.select("img[class=competitive-rank]");
    for(Element el : e){
      playerRankIconURL = el.attr("src");
      println(playerRankIconURL);
    }
```

But it seems to be not working properly...what am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I think you need to change selector like: `rawData.select("div.competitive-rank img")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is looking for an `img` with the class `competitive-rank`, but there isn't one. It's the `div` which has that class.

You probably instead want to select an `img` *which is contained by* a `div` with that class, which you could do with the selector `div.competitive-rank img`.